# Toll fee on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to see the sum of the toll fees of a path on Google Maps?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts lol yeah but that's not very "scalable" :) Since gmaps don't seem to have the information, I've just asked on softwarerecs: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10100/903

Comment: Showing the toll fees would be too complicated since they could vary by vehicle type (or number of axles) and whether you pay cash or use a toll pass.

Comment: @pacoverflow Good point, I remember having the same issue in France: my vehicle type was apparently ambiguous and the toll fee would vary depending on the human operator...